# adding new custom attribute product into cart remove the other cart products

Tags: product, php, checkout, cart, array

I have an issue by adding custom attribute product into cart remove the other already added cart items. I have checked by applying base theme, disabling install module replace the fresh core files of **`code/core/mage/checkout`** directory but issue still existing. Kindly help me to solve this issue thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

seems overriding some code or conflicts. to check conflicts use extension https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/modules-conflict-detector.html.

Please enable log and post what error can you see.

thanks

Comment: I just installed this extension and there is not any conflict just showing below one with red color in rewrite explanation
"Red class name means that probably there is conflict, initial class has been overwritten by this class, but this class is not used. You should check if this class doesn't contain any important methods or changes, which should be used."

Comment: enable log and post what error can you see.

Comment: /home/cupolasd/public_html/app/code/local/Magebuzz/Customstockstatus/Helper/Data.php on line 121
2016-04-27T16:20:03+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: iconHtml  in /home/cupolasd/public_html/app/code/local/Magebuzz/Customstockstatus/Helper/Data.php on line 92
2016-04-27T16:20:03+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: statusId  in /home/cupolasd/public_html/app/code/local/Magebuzz/Customstockstatus/Helper/Data.php on line 121

Comment: Another issue were related to webshopapp matrix rate module i disabled both of these but issue still remains :(

Comment: try to disabled third party extension and check.

Comment: had already done this

Comment: this only happening with products having custom options while all other simple products are adding without removing old items into cart

Comment: posted above error is not related to your issue. They might be some other error in log file.

Comment: i had seen and there were not any except two plugin issues